# Global search/replace on special characters accidentally taken in on an import ( â€™ )

Tags: migrations

I have imported (through CSV using [Feed Import](http://drupal.org/project/feed_import)) and large amount of information. I have a large amount character encoding issues such as

> Grimsbyâ€™s teaching focus is on...

Where `â€™` is in place of the apostrophe. Is there any way to search/replace myself out of this? Could I use an input filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the [scanner module](http://drupal.org/project/scanner) to do these sitewide text search and replace operations but it may be a little tricky because of the characters you're replacing (they look like MS smart quotes?)

Better solution might be to rollback your import, rexport your CSV with a UTF-8 character set and try your import again.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up putting an input filter in place

```
function utf_fix_filter_info() {
    $filters['utf_fix_filter'] = array(
        'title' => t('UTF Fixer'),
        'description' => t('Fixes UTF oppsies'),
        'cache' => TRUE,
        'process callback' => 'utf_fix_substitute',
        'tips callback' => 'utf_fix_filter_tips',
        );

    return $filters;
}

function utf_fix_substitute($text, $filter, $format, $langcode, $cache, $cache_id) {

    $text = str_replace('â&euro;&trade;', "'", $text);

    return $text;
}

function utf_fix_filter_tips($filter, $format, $long) {

    return t('Replaces â&euro;&trade; with an apostrophe');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I successfully used the [Scanner module](https://www.drupal.org/project/scanner) to replace smart/curly quotes with plain quotes.